# Assign values with conditional operator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.net webforms application. When I load a page I bind the DropDownLists this way:

```
ListItem cItem = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("foo");
if(cItem!=null)
{
    cItem.Selected = true;
}
```

Question: Is there a way to do it with the conditional operator?

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("foo")?.Selected = true; //odes not work
```

Comment: why the `?` over there?

Comment: @shahsani because it might be null.